# php function to display which field is not filled in

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, post

I have a simple JavaScript function that will not allow a form to be submitted if all the fields are not filled out. On top of that I would like PHP to write out an error message next to just the fields that are empty. The problem is the function activates upon the `$_POST` and yet my JavaScript function will not allow for `$_POST` to occur as long as one of the fields are empty.

If I keep the action outside of the `$_POST` condition then the page will load with the error message already showing. I am fairly new to PHP and JavaScript and would like any insight on perhaps another available condition that I could use to trigger my error messages to appear in my form. I am also open to any other suggestions for error handling. I do prefer to keep my JavaScript present due to it's ability to keep the form from being submitted if it is not properly filled. Unless there is another way to take that action then I have to keep the JavaScript.

PHP:

```
function cleanCrew ($id, $pswrd) {
    $id = stripslashes($id);
    $pswrd = stripslashes($pswrd);
    $id = strip_tags($id);
    $pswrd = strip_tags($pswrd);

    return array($id, $pswrd);  
}

require_once 'dbServ.php';

$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_base);

if ($db_server) {
    $error_1 = "";
} else{
    $error_1 = "connection to database unsuccessful";
}

$error_2 = "";
$error_3 = "";

if ($_POST) {
    $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST['userId']);
    $user_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $_POST['pass']);
    $id_and_pass = cleanCrew($user_id, $user_pass);

    if ($user_id == "" || $user_id == null) {
        $error_2 = "please fill in proper User Id";
    } else{
        $error_2 = " ";
    }

    if($user_pass == "" || $user_pass == null){
        $error_3 = "please fill out password";
    } else{
        $error_3 = " ";
    }           

    echo $id_and_pass[0];
    echo $id_and_pass[1];
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="intro">
    <h1 id="the_blog" align="center">The <span id="blog_animate" style="position:relative;">Blog</span></h1>
    <div id="log-in"><p id="log">Log In</p><br> <?php echo $error_1;  ?>
        <form action="blog.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" name="form1">
            <p id="log">User ID :</p> <input type="text" placeholder="johnnyApple175" name="userId"></input><?php echo $error_2 ?><br>
            <p id="log">Password:</p> <input type="password" name="pass"></input><?php echo $error_3; ?><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="button" ></input>
        </form>
```

Comment: why dont you write those error msgs (beside the empty form fields) with javascript ?

Comment: Either that or let php handle the blank fields then return errors after the form is posted saying fields can't be blank. Use if(isset($_POST['pass'])) for example

Comment: `any insight on perhaps another available condition that i could use to trigger my error messages to appear in my form` Client side & away from Javascript, you could use HTML5 [required](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html) & [pattern](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/10-pattern.html)

Comment: I haven't looked into HTML5's validation. I'll have to take a look at that and I think I will try changing the value of the error fields using JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

First: 
It's always a very good idea to validate the data server side, like you're doing.
Reason is simple: Javascript is client-side and can easily be modified to e.g. bypass those checks. Also, good that you escaped the sent data prior using it in the Database query.

Your problem is, that you're checking for $_POST to exist - it always exists, it's a super global var. You actually want to check **if it's empty**:

```
if (!empty($_POST))...
```

You might want to think over it, if you really want to give detailed information what exactly was wrong. Giving more info is more user friendly, but it makes attacks easier, especially if you don't block the user after X retries.

Comment: Thanks for the information. If I replace what I have with the !empty($_POST) condition will it jeopardize the functionality at all? I also have not looked at how to block a user out yet i have quite a bit still to go.

Comment: If you replace it with !empty($_POST) as proposed, it will only execute if data is submitted via POST (or you copied data into $_POST). So it should not have an impact on the remaining code.
As an alternative, you can add a hidden input field to the form and check for that, instead of checking for !empty($_POST):
    `<input type="hidden" name="submited" value="1" />`
then:
    `if (isset($_POST['submitted']))`
This is more strict than just checking for an empty POST, but the effect is the same. Avoid checking for the submit button value, some browsers don't send that in some cases.